# Livepatch problem. Cloned?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Ubuntu 20.4.2 LTS - FOCAL

My laptop was working fine and the Internet speed fine. This, until ew days ago when the Internet speed went down dramatically. It's now 50 to 60% slower.

- I didn't change any settings.
- I didn't install or remove any software.
- I'm not going to websites I never went to before.

Today I noticed that the icon for the live patch's status isn't showing anymore and I don't know since when. So I went to the software control panel and  saw that Live Patch was disabled. I am 500% sure I didn't do that. I always wanted it to be enabled since day one. So I tried to enable it and it doesn't work. The error message says:

> Failed to enable Livepatch: cannot enable machine: this machine ID is already enabled with a different key or is non-unique. Either "sudo canonical-livepatch disable" on the other machine, or regenerate a unique /etc/machine-id on this machine with "sudo rm /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id && sudo systemd-machine-id-setup" server response: machine id already registered: machine id already registered"

I did a shutdown then restarted my laptop and same thing, same problem.

What could have caused that? I don't have any other computer so impossible that I have the same key or same machine ID elsewhere. Is it possible that a hacker cloned my computer to spy on me? How can I ix this?

Also, how can I monitor my Internet connection and what to look for to check if I'm being spyed on?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you run the command to regenerate the machine ID? It's just a random string, so it's possible somebody else also randomly arrived at the same ID.

Comment: Hi Zanna, no I did not run that command. What are the odds that someone arrived at the same string???

Comment: About 1 in 10^40.